# How do I use powershell to close a program after another program closes?

Tags: powershell, auto-close

Is there a way to run `Stop-Process` after a specific program closes itself automatically?

I am trying to close my VPN client after my torrent client closes itself.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `Wait-Process`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/wait-process?view=powershell-7

```
Wait-Process -Name "TorrentClientProcessName"
Stop-Process -Name "VPNClientProcessName "
```

This script waits until the Torrent client has exited and then closes VPNClient. You have to replace TorrentClientProcessName and VPNClientProcessName with their process names.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was way easier than expected

Comment: Done, sorry about that. First time I pose a question on here.

Comment: Thank you very much for that. Hope you have happy coding!